# 406 Not Acceptable en retrofit

Tags: java, android-studio, webservice, retrofit

Me esta sucediendo un problema cuando intento consumir un servicio me sale este mensaje **406 Not Acceptable** y no se como solucionarlo, revise el modelo y los datos estaban bien y el body me llega null

adjunto imagen de lo que me sucede

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el método donde le paso los datos y realizo la petición POST  hago el llamado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código que estas utilizando para que asi te puedan ayudar

Comment: Ok ya coloque el codigo

Comment: @stivmen cuando agregues código te sugiero realizarlo como texto para que sea más legible, saludos!